# Deploying Azure Resource Group project as a part of MsBuild script

Tags: msbuild, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to migrate our solution from classic to Resource Manager deployment and I've stuck with running the RM deployment as a step of MsBuild build script. For the classic project there is

```
      <MSBuild Projects="SomeAzureProject\SomeAzureProject.ccproj"
                     Targets="Publish"
                     Properties="
                     VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
                     Configuration=$(CloudConfiguration);
                     Platform=$(Platform);
                     TargetProfile=$(CloudTargetProfile);
                     PublishProfile=$(CloudPublishProfile);
                     PublishDir=$(CloudPublishDir);"></MSBuild>
```

build step.

Is there something like this for the .deployproj ? If yes - what parameters should be passed to it? (we need to be able to pass at least resource group name, params file name and the template file name).